# CSS grid being partially responsive

Tags: html, css, gridview, css-grid

I am trying to build a simple `navbar` and `footer` in a 16 column grid using the following html code.

[image: iPhone 5 crops screen]

```css
*{
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        }
        
        .grid{
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
         grid-column-gap: 10px;
        }
        
        .title{
         grid-column: 1/15;
         background-color: #269acb;
         display:grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        }
        .nav{
         display:grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
        }
        
        .logo{
         padding:20px 40px 20px 20px;
        }
        
        .menu{
         padding:30px 5px 20px 5px;
         font-size: 12px;
         color: #ffffff;
         text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .social{
         display:grid;
         grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
         justify-self: end;
         
        }
        
        .schedule{
         background-color: #269acb;
         border-radius: 5px;
         border: 1px solid #ffffff;
         margin:13px 10px 13px;
         color: #ffffff;
         vertical-align: middle;
         
        }
        
        .icon{
         padding:30px 5px 20px 5px;
        }
        
        
        .footer{
         grid-column: 1/15;
         background-color: #155570;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
         grid-template-row: repeat(3, 1fr);
         grid-column-gap: 10px;
         
        }
        
        footer .a{
         text-decoration: none;
         color:#ffffff;
         
        }
        
        
        .footerlogo{
         grid-row:1/2;
         grid-column: 2/3;
         
        }
        
        .footerlink{
         text-decoration: none;
         color:#ffffff;
        }
        .footer-col1{
          grid-row:1/2;
          grid-column: 4/6;
        }
        
        .footer-col2{
          grid-row:1/2;
          grid-column: 6/8;
        }
        .footer-col3{
          grid-row:1/2;
          grid-column: 8/10;
        }
        .footer-col4{
          grid-row:1/2;
          grid-column: 10/12;
          justify-self: end;
        }
        
        .subscribe{
         grid-row:2/3;
         grid-column:10/14;
         justify-self: center;
        }
        
        .copyright{
         grid-row:3/4;
         grid-column:2/5;
         font-size: 10px;
        }
```

```html
     <!-- start of  container grid -->
      <div class="grid">
       <!-- start of  header -->
      
       <div class="title">
        <div class="nav">
         <img src="Home Page-assets/logo.png" alt="logo"class="logo">
         <a href="" class="menu">ABOUT US</a>
         <a href="" class="menu">STUDENT</a>
         <a href="" class="menu">PROPERTY OWNER</a>
         <a href="" class="menu">PEER AND LEARN</a>
         <a href="" class="menu">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="social">
         <button class="schedule">SCHEDULE VISIT</button>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/insta.png" alt="insta icon" class="icon"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/twit.png" alt="twitter icon" class="icon"</a>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/fb.png"alt="FB icon"  class="icon"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/down.png" alt="dummy icon" class="icon"></a>
        </div>
       
       </div>
       
       <!-- end of  header -->
       <!-- start of  footer -->
       
       <div class="footer">
        <img src="Home Page-assets/logo.png" alt="logo"  class="footerlogo">
        <div class="footer-col1"><a href="" class="">About Us><br><a href="" class="">student</a><br><a href="" class="">property owner</a><br><a href="" class="">refer and earn</a></div>
        <div class="footer-col2"><a href="" class="">Career></a><br><a href="" class="">blog</a><br><a href="" class="">gallery</a><br><a href="" class="">media</a></div>
        <div class="footer-col3"><a href="" class="">Contact us><br><a href="" class="">Terms &#38 Conditions</a><br><a href="" class="">Privacy Policies</a><br><a href="" class="">FAQ's</a></div>
        <div class="footer-col4">
         <p>Follow Us</p><br>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/insta.png" alt="insta icon" class="icon"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/twit.png" alt="twitter icon" class="icon"</a>
         <a href="#"><img src="Home Page-assets/fb.png"alt="FB icon"  class="icon"></a>
        
        </div>
        <div class="subscribe">
         <input type="text" class="inputform" placeholder="yourmail@domain.com"/>
         <button>subscribe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">Copyright&#x24B8 2019| All rights reserved by InstaDwell</div>
       </div>
       <!-- end of  footer -->
       
      </div>
```

However, my code is not responsive for smaller devices like `iPhone 5` and just marginal for `iPad`. what can be the possible error? I am using a `16 column grid`. In desktop mode it appears fine as I shrink the browser width the contents behave responsively up to a width and then they are completely hidden after around `700px`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your grid setup depending on the screen width. You can do that with media queries at the bottom of your CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .grid {
        // properties
    }

    .footer {
        // properties
    }
    // ...
}
```

What this does is change the CSS when the screen size is greater than or equal to 700px. Note that the browser applies the CSS outside of the `@media` query if the screen size is less than 700px, then applies the CSS inside of media query if the screen size is greater than 700px.

This way, you can essentially create completely different styles that change depending on the screen size and in your case, you can change the grid layout for a smaller screen so that the content can actually fit on your screen.